# Matching search phrase occurrence to boolean field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to create a text-based query that could match value from a boolean field.

In words of example – my query could be "Red carpet artificial" or "Artificial red carpet" and I have documents with boolean field mapped as `artificial: true/false`. With that phrases I need to match documents that have `artificial: true`.

---

This is the data stored in index:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Fast car",
    "artificial": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Red carpet",
    "artificial": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Green carpet of grass",
    "artificial": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Lovely bunny",
    "artificial": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Big house",
    "artificial": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Green plant",
    "artificial": false
  }
]
```

Now I have user-input search phrases like:

- "Artificial carpet"
- "Carpet (artificial)"
- "Carpet – Artificial"

I need to construct query that when entering above phrases will always return:

```
  {
    "name": "Red carpet",
    "artificial": true
  }
```

But when user enters:

- "Carpet"

It will actually return:

```
  {
    "name": "Green carpet of grass",
    "artificial": false
  }
```

(Or both "carpet"-consisting documents it that would be easier to achieve.)

The thing is I need search phrase tokenization here, because "artificial" can be named in different kind of ways.

And "artificial" is my keyword that does not suppose to change.

---

Is there a mechanism or some kind of workflow in Elasticsearch to achieve this? Maybe re-mapping `artificial: (bool) true/false` to `artificial: (keyword) artificial/null` or something? How would query look like then?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using new 7.11 Elasticsearch feature called [Runtime mapping fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/runtime-mapping-fields.html).

Created new field based on boolean field that converts true/false to keyword representation of this field versus empty string. Then – used "terms" query.

```json
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "myfield_keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit(doc['myfield'].value ? 'value' : '')"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "boost": 2,
            "myfield_keyword": [
              "search",
              "phrase",
              "tokenized",
              "manually"
            ]
          }
        },
// ...
```